# Input "cobra" to output "dpcsb" Translating 1 char to next c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, lookup-tables

the problem is:
Write a simple program to encrypt a text string using a look up table or a simple algorithm; for example, text string "Hello World" could be encrypted into string "ifmmp xpqme" simply by translating each character to the next letter of the alphabet

```
  char inputwords[100];
char *words;
char y='w';
int x=0;

cout<<"Enter word: ";
cin>>inputwords;

words=&inputwords[0];


for(int ctr=0;ctr<100;ctr++)
{
    if(*(words+ctr)+1==1||*(words+ctr)+1==-51)
        cout<<" ";
    else
    cout<<char(*(words+ctr)+1);
}
```

Here is the code fragment
my problem is when i input "Hello World" the output is only "ifmmp" and it disregards the "World". Help :(

Comment: `ctr<100`, `+1==1`, `-51`... lots of weird things.

Comment: That example is bad to begin with, because it doesn't just "simply by translating each character to the next letter of the alphabet", it also changes the case of two of the characters...

Answer (score 2):

`cin` using `>>` on input stream reads only first word which in your case it is just `Hello` skipping `World`. So to read whole multi word string into `char` array `inputwords` use,

```
cin.getline(inputwords, sizeof(inputwords));
```

The `for` loop iterates `100` times no matter what is your input string which will result in garbage values after the string.

You need handle case such as, if there is a space in between two words make out put remain same and not advance it resulting to `!`.

Answer (score 1):

You are coding in C++. Use `std::string` and STL's algorithms instead of old fashioned C arrays and hand made loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //encryption function, maths may be wrong.
    auto f=[](char &x){x=(x+1)%255;};

    //decryption function, maths may be wrong too.
    auto g=[](char &x){x=(x-1)%255;};

    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin,s);

    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
    std::for_each(std::begin(s),std::end(s),f);
    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;

    std::for_each(std::begin(s),std::end(s),g);
    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Edit : C++11 required for the lambda, can be easily adapted to be used with a C++03 compiler.

Edit 2 : see it in action there -> http://ideone.com/SjeVaQ

Answer (score 0):

1. Use getline instead of cin to get the whole line instead of the first word.
2. Iterate till the end of the string, not an arbitrary 0.
3. Compare against the original value, not the +1 value. Dont test if current +1 is 1, test if current is 0.

   ```
   char *itr = inputwords;
   for ( ; *itr; ++itr ) {
       char curr = *itr;
   }
   ```

   1. Dont forget to handle 'z' and 'Z'